# Calculating mean from multiple folder using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I am writing a script to loop through multiple folders and calculate mean of the raster of each folder's data sets and save it in same folder. Below script i am working, but its not producing  the mean rasters for each year folder, after running the script its generating only name of "mean" raster in main folder, and overlapping it .

Below images showing the name of the raster in one folder, another folder the raster name is same, only year value is changed in different year.
here how to take the year value in name of mean raster (E.g. for 2001 folder, output mean raster name would be Mean_RAIN_2001.tiff)

[image]

Script:

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = r"D:\Test"
outraster = env.workspace


walk = arcpy.da.Walk(env.workspace, topdown=True, datatype="RasterDataset")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    print dirpath
    rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters("TIF")
    print rasterList

    for Rasters in rasterList:
        rasMean = CellStatistics(Rasters,"MEAN", "DATA")
        file_name_only = os.path.splitext(Rasters)[0]
        tifname = file_name_only[-4:]
        rasMean.save(os.path.join(outraster,'Mean_{0}.tif'.format(tifname)))
        print rasMean
```

Printing statement: its printing only folder name,

```
D:\Test
[]
D:\Test\2001A
[]
D:\Test\2002A
[]
D:\Test\2003A
[]
D:\Test\2004A
[]
D:\Test\2005A
[]
D:\Test\2006A
[]
D:\Test\2007A
[]
D:\Test\2008A
[]
D:\Test\2009A
[]
```

Comment: As you will see in the [code snippet recommendations](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) it is best to remove any `try`/`except` statements while testing.

Comment: yes, i removed try/except statements  and rerun the code, now its producing error

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the full error message, and the output from any `print` statements from running this code.

Comment: i did little change the code, now its not showing any error but generating only one output name of "mean" in test folder. even output of raster  not goes to subfolder to save it in each folder.

Comment: We need to see precisely the code snippet that you are running in your test, and precisely the output (from errors and print statements) from running that code snippet.

Comment: Which script is existing with my question, that script not producing any error while the script producing single output, name of output Mean.tif and overlapping multiple times in main folder (D./Test), output of raster not save in source of input raster folder (E.g. Input folder: D./Test/2001)

Comment: It sounds like you have two scripts. Which one are you asking about?  That is the one that needs to be reduced to a code snippet and presented here along with any output from it. The shorter you can make that code snippet the quicker you are likely to attract a potential answerer to help you past the first issue you have with it.

Comment: i removed the line gap from script. Whichever is existing with my question  i asking that only.

Comment: Where's the output of those two print statements?  I would print rasterList too.

Comment: i added the print statement and print list

Answer (score 1):

I can see several things wrong with this script. Firstly you keep overwriting your output with this line:

```
rasMean.save(os.path.join(outraster,"mean.tif"))
```

The reasons for that is `outraster` never changes as it comes from the environment settings which you set to d:\test. `outraster` needs to change with each level that you are looping over (a concatenation of dirpath and dirnames).

I think it would be a good idea if you experiment with the walk() function and understand what it is generating as this is the source of your problem.

Secondly the tool CellStatistics takes as input a list of rasters, but your current code is building the list and calling the tool *within* your "for file in filenames" loop which is horribly inefficient. You need to build the list then feed that into the tool so all you need to do is remove the indentation from the 3 lines after the append call so they fall outside the loop.

Comment: thank you. can i get some idea how to reconstruct the code .

Comment: please help me to reconstruct the code